# How to understand the relationship between PDE and modular homomorphism

Tags: partial-differential-equations, commutative-algebra

When learning Commutative Algebra, I was asked how to understand the relationship between PDE and modular homomorphism. To speak specifically, the relationship between PDEs in $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathrm{Hom}(R/I,C^∞(\mathbb R^n))$, when $I$ is an ideal of $R$, $R=\mathbb R[x_1,...,x_n,∂/∂x_1,...,∂/∂x_n]$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a volume in $\mathbb R^n$, $\ \partial V$ its boundary and $$\mathit C(V)\ : \quad \left\{ f: \vec x \to f(\vec x) \in \mathbb C \right\}$$
the linear space of smooth complex functions over $V.$

The linear operator $D(x_k,\partial_{x_k})$ of an inhomogenous  PDE
$$D(x_1\dots,\partial_{x_1}\dots) \ f(x_1 \dots)=g(x_1\dots)  \quad \forall x \in V, \quad \vec \alpha \cdot \nabla_x f(x) + \beta f(x) =0 \quad \forall x \in \partial V $$  represents an endomorphism for a subset of $\mathit C(V)$ obeying the boundary conditon.

It may have a non trivial kernel $I$ of solutions,

$$D(x_1\dots,\partial_{x_1}\dots)\ f_I(x_1 \dots)=0$$

Then the general solution is a the sum of an arbitrary special solution plus a linear combination of elements from the kernel.

The art of solving is to determine the kernel and invert the endomorphism on the quotient space of  endomorphism of $\mathit C(V) \  \text{mod} \ I.$, typically by an integral that involves a basis in the kernel and the boundary.

Easiest case: Complex unit circle, $$\partial_{z,\overline z} f = g, \quad f(z, |z|=1)=h(z) $$